# Website keeps going to http://MyWebsite.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php

Tags: wordpress, configuration

My website keeps going Website keeps going to http://MyWebsite.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php. Can you help? Thank you

Comment: Here is my .htaccess info:

Answer (score 0):

If WordPress can't find the tables in the database, it will be redirected to the setup process. This usually occur when you transfer the website to another host and the prefix is different. Check your wp-config.php for the table prefix to see if it matches what's on the database.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess doesn't have anything to do with this. If your site was running before and you're suddenly gettting the Install screen, your database details in `wp-config.php` have changed, such as the database name and/or table prefix. Check those. You are connecting to the database, as you're not getting a database error. But your table prefix or database name was changed.